# Comment Formatting Goes Awry

Tags: bug, comments, formatting

I just tried to add a Comment to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163464/im-moving-to-germany-but-want-to-keep-my-uk-job-any-advice). My proposed comment contained a basic link to expatriates.stackexchange.com. The form of the comment was the basic link formatting for Comments, but the formatting didn't take.

When I try to type here what I typed there, my typing is truncated and doesn't appear completely. Here's an image of what I typed:

[image]

I typed the above, but the comment appeared just as the image shows it, the word "Expatriates" not in red and not as a link.

Anyone know what's up?

Comment: presumably just because you need https://?

Comment: @MarkMayo Thanks, that was it. Including "https://" makes the link appear correctly.

Comment: Urls "should" be copied and pasted...and any link clicked to test ;)

Answer (score 1):

@MarkMayo was correct: the comment didn't format correctly because I had omitted the "https://" part of the URL. With the entire URL included, the comment formatted correctly.